# How to present a PDF with notes on presenter screen?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, beamer, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for presenting PDF slides with presenter notes on second display](https://superuser.com/questions/339404/tools-for-presenting-pdf-slides-with-presenter-notes-on-second-display)

I want to show a presentation such that the slides are shown on the projector while I see slide-related notes on my laptop screen.

I am using Windows.

1. Which program can I use to show such a split presentation of a PDF?
2. How do I create such a PDF with presenter notes? (I use both latex/beamer and PowerPoint)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is working for [LaTeX/Beamer under Windows](http://bartvanbeek.net/?p=129) too.

1. Download and install [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html).

   (even if you don’t use Beamer, it might be a good idea to install this tiny pdf-reader as it has the huge benefit of allowing [inverse search](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/sumatra/index.html)).
2. Download and and extract [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/duallauncher.html).
3. I assume that you’ve already installed the Beamer class.

   Add the following to the preamble of your Latex-document, and create a pdf  as usual :

   `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}`
4. Go to the folder where you’ve extracted the Dual Monitor Tools and open DualLauncher.exe. You should now see a tiny screen-shaped icon on your taskbar, click on the icon with you right mouse button and select Add New Magic Word.
5. You are now presented with a screen that will help you to span Sumatra PDF across two screens. Fill in the following:

   - **Magic word:** `sumatra` (choose any word you like)
   - **Filename:** `C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe`
     (assuming Sumatra PDF is installed in the default location)
   - **Parameters:** `-presentation "name and location of file you want to present"`
   - **Start position 1:** select Position window on startup and assuming your beamer has a resolution of 1024 x 768 fill in Size: 2048,768.
   - Click OK
6. Plugin your second screen or beamer and ensure that you beamer actually displays the action from your computer.
7. Use the Windows key + P to set your beamer as an adjacent screen an make sure that this screen is to the (virtual) right of your normal screen. You can check whether it’s set correctly by right-clicking on you desktop and selecting screen resolution. If everything has been set up as it should, you should see two screens there, which you can drag  into position.
8. Right-click on the Dual Launcher icon and select Enter Magic Word, double-click on the Sumatra PDF icon and everything should display as you want it to.

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop supports true multiple displays (not just mirroring), PowerPoint's presenter view lets you project just the slides while you see your notes, a small version of the slide and, depending on version, next/previous slides on your laptop screen.

I don't understand what you mean by "such a PDF" ... one that can display on two screens as with presenter view in PPT?  But you can print Notes Pages to your PDF printer driver from PowerPoint and get pages with a slide image + your notes.

Comment: If you don't have to use PDF, Powerpoint has been capable of doing this for sometime using the Presenter view.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a proper way to do this. A simple work around is to make one document span two screens with the notes being on one side and the presentation on the other.

http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/624776419

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The link you post mentions a work around solution for Mac OS, not for Windows.  Also, I was hoping for a better solution, not a work around.